# Python multiprocessing queue not sharing queue items

Tags: python, queue

I am creating two processes. One which will add a int value to a Mutliprocessing.Queue from 1 to 5. The other will also add to the Queue one time and then it will loop for 10 seconds and try to read values from the Queue.

Why can my second process not get items added to the queue in my first thread? I was under the assumption that when creating a Multiprocessing.Queue that i could add to it from one process and it would be able to be read by another process. It looks as if its only adding to the Qeueu that is passed and not the parent Queue. Can i not add items to some type of Queue from 2 different processes created by the parent?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time


def f(q):

    for a in range(5):
        print "Adding to Q!"
        time.sleep(1)
        q.put(a)

def g(q):

    i = 0
    v = True
    q.put("Adding to this q")
    while v == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i = i + 1
        print "Get slept time " , i
        try:
                print "From the q " + str(q.get(True,1))
        except:
                print "Empty"
        if i == 10:
                v = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue(10)
    print "First process"
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    print "Second Process"
    p1 = Process(target=g, args=(q,))
    p1.start()

    p.join()
    p1.join()
```

## Adding or removing the join() seems to have no affect on the desired output

My output as of now. ** it is not the desired output **

```
First process
Second Process
Adding to Q!
Get slept time  1
From the q Adding to this q
Adding to Q!
Get slept time  2
Adding to Q!
Empty
Get slept time  3
Adding to Q!
Empty
Get slept time  4
Adding to Q!
Empty
Get slept time  5
Empty
Get slept time  6
Empty
Get slept time  7
Empty
Get slept time  8
Empty
Get slept time  9
Empty
Get slept time  10
Empty
```

Comment: Tested it on centos 6.5 with python 2.6 x64 and I got the desired output.

Comment: Did you get the output that i had? Or did you get a different output? Can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the problem is not with the queue,
it's in your `print "From the q " + q.get(True,1)`

your exception is `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

you better use `print "From the q {}".format(q.get(True,1))`

@tiggles
    Edited after your coment: 
there is no problem reading / writing from the queue. 
here is the code examples that just works:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def f(q):

    for a in range(5):      
        time.sleep(1)
        q.put(a)

def g(q):

    i = 0
    v = True
    q.put("Adding to this q")
    while v == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i = i + 1
        print "Get slept time " , i
        try:
            print "From the q {}".format(q.get(True,1)) 
        except Exception as e:
            print 'exception raised {} {}'.format(e, type(e))
            print "Empty"
        if i == 10:
            v = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue(10)
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    p1 = Process(target=g, args=(q,))
    p1.start()

    p.join()
    p1.join()
    print q.qsize(), q.empty()
```

and the results:

```
Get slept time  1
From the q Adding to this q
Get slept time  2
From the q 0
Get slept time  3
From the q 1
Get slept time  4
From the q 2
Get slept time  5
From the q 3
Get slept time  6
From the q 4
Get slept time  7
exception raised  <class 'Queue.Empty'>
Empty
Get slept time  8
exception raised  <class 'Queue.Empty'>
Empty
Get slept time  9
exception raised  <class 'Queue.Empty'>
Empty
Get slept time  10
exception raised  <class 'Queue.Empty'>
Empty
0 True
```

any questions?

Comment: Yea i had cast it to a string but i must have not copied that code over and missed where i cast it. But even fixing that issue does not fix why i cannot read the values from the queue by the first thread

Comment: @tiggles did you notice my changes?

Comment: Yes, now i see and it works fine with the .format(q.get(True,1)). I understand why i wasn't see the error you were getting because i wasn't printing the exception output. I was only printing "Empty". Thank you for help